# Why does checkSelfPermissions() return null ? (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to peform a little permission check as test, but it 
gives me this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>       at com.doppler.stackingcoder.pechhulp.PechhulpActivity.makeCall(PechhulpActivity.java:238)

And here is my method where the error appears:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void makeCall() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Geen toestemming om te bellen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I hope someone knows the issue, thanks in advance!

EDIT : Whole class: https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/6363463ef1fb1988af4fb6f9e7e8b228

I am calling the method, ( makeCall ) from another class , called CustomDialogClass.java. here is a gist of that class:

https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/bcf045f80e4f9c9b95994dafdf1ba682

Comment: What Android API level are you using ?

Comment: Android 6.0 so i think level 23

Answer (score 0):

Introduced in API level 23, you can use the checkSelfPermission method from your Activity instance (make sure you use the instance of the Activity and not a static reference of the Activity class).

```
yourActivityInstance.checkSelfPermission(String permision);
```

Specifically in your case:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void makeCall() {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09003344556"));
    boolean hasCallPhonePermission = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    if (!hasCallPhonePermission){
        // The app does not have permission to phone call !
        return;
    }
    // The app has permission to phone call
}
```

Comment: What is my ActivityInstance ?

Comment: If your makeCell method is inside your Activity class and the Activity is running, you can use 'this' to reference to the current Activity instance.

Comment: Yes i am trying, but it gives me this error: checkSelfPermission in ContextWrapper cannot be applied EDIT: Now i have just inserted the activity name: PechhulpActivity but now it gives me this red underline error: Non-static method checkSelfPermission cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/6363463ef1fb1988af4fb6f9e7e8b228

Comment: Iv'e edit the answer and provided an example per your code. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I am getting the same error:                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
I am calling the method from another class, called CustomDialogClass, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118922/discussion-between-dudu-lev-and-stackingcoder).